# How to define a default argument value in template toolkit MACRO

Tags: perl, template-toolkit

I want to define a Template Toolkit MACRO with few arguments, and have at least one of them with a default value if no argument is given in that position. Is it possible?
My idea is to have something like this (similar to Python syntax/logic):

```
[%- 
    MACRO my_macro( arg1, arg2, arg3='my_default_value') BLOCK;
        # arg3 value is 'my_default_value' if nothing is passed as argument in that position, otherwise it must use arg3 value given when called.
    END;
-%]
```

And then to call the macro:

```
# In this case, arg3 inside the macro must be 'my_default_value'
my_macro('my_value1', 'my_value2');

# In this case, arg3 inside the macro must be 'my_value3'
my_macro('my_value1', 'my_value2', 'my_value3');
```

Comment: Maybe you could use the `PERL` directive at the beginning of the macro block to modify the stash? The stash variable will be set to the empty string if it is not given as an argument, so you could do something like `my $arg3 = $stash->get('arg3'); $arg3 = 'my_default_value' if $arg3 eq ""; $stash->set(arg3 => $arg3)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've no doubt found, your suggested syntax throws a syntax error. Because TT doesn't support that.

You can take the approach that [Håkon takes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68451484/7231), but if you want something a little simpler, that doesn't require a `[% PERL %]` block, you can do something like this:

```
[% MACRO my_macro( arg1, arg2, arg3) BLOCK;
     arg3 = 'my default value' IF NOT arg3.defined -%]

Arg 3 is [% arg3 %]
[% END -%]
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand this line
_Arg 3 is [% arg3 %]_ Are you sure is correct?

Comment: @eduardosufan: Yes, it's correct. I have no idea what your macro needed to do, so I just produced the simplest debugging output I could. It displays the string "Arg 3 is" followed by the value of `arg3`. What don't you understand?

Comment: Ohh I didn't see that's a string. Now I understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how you can modify the stash using a `PERL` directive if a macro argument was not provided. This can by used to implement default values for the arguments to the macro:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Template;

my $template = Template->new({ EVAL_PERL => 1});
my $vars = { };
my $input = <<'END';
[%- MACRO my_macro(arg1, arg2, arg3) BLOCK -%]
  [% PERL %]
     my $arg3 = $stash->get('arg3');
     $arg3 = "my_default_value" if $arg3 eq "";
     $stash->set(arg3 => $arg3)
  [% END %]
  This is arg1 : [% arg1 %]
  This is arg2 : [% arg2 %]
  This is arg3 : [% arg3 -%]
[%- END -%]

Case 1: [% my_macro(1, 2, 3) %],
Case 2: [% my_macro("a","b") %],

END

$template->process(\$input, $vars) || die $template->error();
```

**Output**:

```
Case 1:   
  This is arg1 : 1
  This is arg2 : 2
  This is arg3 : 3,
Case 2:   
  This is arg1 : a
  This is arg2 : b
  This is arg3 : my_default_value,
```

Comment: This is interesting. If you call `[% arg3.defined %]` on entering the macro, you'll see that `arg3` is undefined. But in the Perl code, `$stash->get('arg3')` returns a defined value. So you can't differentiate between no argument and an empty string.

Comment: Yeah, calling `[% my_macro("a","b","") %]` gives you the default value.